# R package CEM: Error in `[.data.frame`(TEi, idt) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform coarsened exact matching with the R package `CEM`. I have a data frame of observations (no missing observations, for colnames see below) and am trying to:

1. perform CEM with depression (depres6mo) as the treatment to match on, then
2. perform linear regression with the matched dataset with opiates as the outcome (opiates_sum1yr).

When I run the code below, I get the error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(TEi, idt) : undefined columns selected

However, I've double checked that all of the variables I'm regressing on are variables in the data frame. Any idea what's going on?

```
colnames(nonMissing)  
# [1] "depres6mo"      "alcohol"        "obesity"        "ageGrp"         "sex"            "geoRegion"     
# [7] "year"           "multi_lami"     "multi_fusion"   "single_lami"    "instr"          "htn"           
# [13] "chf"            "copd"           "MI"             "diab_u"         "diab_c"         "drug"          
# [19] "tbco"           "planType"       "opiates_sum1yr" "daily"   


mod_match <-  cem(treatment = "depres6mo", data = nonMissing, drop = c("opiates_sum1yr", "daily"))  
opiatesLin <- att(mod_match, opiates_sum1yr ~ depres6mo + alcohol + obesity + ageGrp + sex + geoRegion + year + multi_lami + multi_fusion + single_lami + instr + htn + chf + copd + MI + diab_u + diab_c + drug + tbco + planType, data = nonMissing)
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(TEi, idt) : undefined columns selected

Answer (score 5):

I received the same error and found out it was because my data_frame was a tibble as I use tidyverse. Once I switched to data.frame() instead of data_frame(), the att() worked.